# Distância entre dois pontos

Tags: java, java-8

Leia os quatro valores correspondentes aos eixos `x` e `y` de dois pontos quaisquer no plano `p1(x1,y1)` e `p2(x2,y2)` e calcule a distância entre eles, mostrando 4 casas decimais após a vírgula, segundo a fórmula:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo de entrada contém duas linhas de dados. A primeira linha contém dois valores de ponto flutuante: `x1 y1` e a segunda linha contém dois valores de ponto flutuante `x2 y2`.
Saída
Calcule e imprima o valor da distância segundo a fórmula fornecida, com 4 casas após o ponto decimal.

Exemplo de Entrada

```
1.0 7.0   
5.0 9.0 
saida = 4.4721

entrada   
-2.5 0.4  
12.1 7.3    
saída = 16.1484
```

Meu código esta dessa maneira

```
import java.util.*;

public class Problema {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        Formatter formato = new Formatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        String valoresX;
        String valoresY;

        valoresX = entrada.nextLine(); //pega valores da 1º linha no caso -2.5 0.4
        valoresY = entrada.nextLine();//pega valores da 2º linha no caso 12.1 7.3

        String[] eixosX = valoresX.split(" "); // aqui jogo os valores separados de x em cada posição do vetor eixosX  
        double x1 = Double.parseDouble(eixosX[0]); //Converto a string para double
        double x2 = Double.parseDouble(eixosX[1]);//o mesmo aqui

        String[] eixosY = valoresY.split(" "); // mesmos passos acima mas agora para y
        double y1 = Double.parseDouble(eixosY[0]);
        double y2 = Double.parseDouble(eixosY[1]);



        double distancia = Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * 2 + (y2 - y1) * 2);

        formato.format("%.4f", distancia);

        System.out.println(formato);

        entrada.close();

    }

}
```

minha dificuldade esta no exemplo da segunda entrada onde passo -2.5 (espaço) 0.4 na 1º linha e 12.1(espaço) 7.3 na 2º linha e o resultado retornado e NaN, preciso que a saída seja 16.1484.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se esta entrada:

```
-2.5 0.4  
12.1 7.3
```

Corresponde a:

```
x1 y1
x2 y2
```

Então primeiro você deve corrigir a ordem em que as coisas são lidas. Você está considerando que a primeira linha tem x1 e x2, quando na verdade ela tem x1 e **y1**.
O mesmo vale para a segunda linha (tem x2 e y2, mas você está lendo como se fosse **y1** e y2), então o código para ler os números ficaria assim:

```
String primeiraLinha = entrada.nextLine(); // pega valores da 1º linha no caso -2.5 0.4
String segundaLinha = entrada.nextLine();// pega valores da 2º linha no caso 12.1 7.3

String[] eixosPrimeiraLinha = primeiraLinha.split(" ");
double x1 = Double.parseDouble(eixosPrimeiraLinha[0]);
double y1 = Double.parseDouble(eixosPrimeiraLinha[1]);// aqui é y1, e não x2

String[] eixosSegundaLinha = segundaLinha.split(" "); 
double x2 = Double.parseDouble(eixosSegundaLinha[0]); // aqui é x2, e não y1
double y2 = Double.parseDouble(eixosSegundaLinha[1]);
```

Outro detalhe é que ao fazer `(x2 - x1) * 2`, você está **multiplicando** (x2 - x1) por 2. Para elevar ao quadrado, use `Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2)`.

Portanto, o cálculo fica assim:

```
double distancia = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
```

Com isso, o valor da distância é `16.1484`.

---

Outro modo de fazer é usar `nextDouble()`, que já retorna um `double` diretamente.
A diferença é que o `Scanner` deve ter um `java.util.Locale` setado para reconhecer o ponto (`.`) como o separador decimal.

Caso você não use um `Locale`, ele vai usar o *default* da JVM e o separador pode não ser o `.` (na minha JVM, por exemplo, o locale *default* é `pt_BR`, e o separador decimal é a vírgula).

Então o código fica assim:

```
// usar Locale.US para usar ponto como separador decimal
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);

// ler valores
double x1 = entrada.nextDouble();
double y1 = entrada.nextDouble();
double x2 = entrada.nextDouble();
double y2 = entrada.nextDouble();

// calcular distância
double distancia = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
```

A diferença é que `nextDouble()` vai ler os números independente deles estarem na mesma linha ou não. Já o código com `nextLine()` e `split()` só funciona se tiver pelo menos dois números na mesma linha (caso haja mais, eles são ignorados pelo nosso código, pois ele só considera as duas primeiras posições).